# why validity extended ca does not contain private key information?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I have one self signed rootcacert.pem which is going to expire next
month. Due to specific reason I have extended the validity of  this
rootcacert using the command :

openssl x509 -in rootcacert.pem -days 365 -out extendedrootcacert.pem -
signkey rootcakey.pem -text

So I get the new root ca as extendedrootcacert.pem. Using new root ca,
I am able to use user certificate signed by old root ca as well as
newer user certificates signed by this new root ca. All functionality
works fine without any problem.

But when I opened this extendedrootcacert.pem  & original
rootcacert.pem file using notepad, I found that there is a difference
between the contents.

The rootcacert.pem has private key and other information(Private-
Key,publicExponent,privateExponent,prime1,prime2,exponent1,exponent2,coefficient),
which looks like :

http://ospkibook.sourceforge.net/docs/OSPKI-2.4.7/OSPKI-html/sample-key-components.htm

But the new  extendedrootcacert.pem does not have this information in
it.
All other field are same in both the certificate.

I dont know how the original rootcacert.pem was generated.

Will there be any adversed impact on my application's functionality.
Is there any way to include this information in the new extended root
ca. Is it absolutely necessary to have this information in new
extended root ca.?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: You link is wrong (404). Probably truncated.

Comment: Sorry the link is broken. The correct link is 

http://ospkibook.sourceforge.net/docs/OSPKI-2.4.7/OSPKI-html/sample-key-components.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your link is erronous.

The important part for the certificate is between the lines:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
…
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

All human comprehensible outside are only for human consumption.

You can do a fresh dump of both informations with:

```
openssl x509 -in rootca.pem -noout -text
openssl x509 -in extendedrootca.pem -noout -text
```

and compare them.

It is also probable that your rootca.pem combine *both* the key and the certificate in one single file.  In this case you will find lines like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You should then add that to your extendedrootca.pem.